# Is the Prasada / Nirmalya of Shiva impure and leads to hell?

Tags: scripture, shiva, puranas, padma-purana, prasad

[Padma purana Uttara khanda Chapter 255](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365840.html) mentions the following -

> 98-101. Therefore, brāhmaṇas should always eat the remnants of the
> food offered to Viṣṇu. The remnants (of food offered to other gods)
> are useless and (therefore) condemned. **A brāhmaṇa, weak in
> knowledge, who even once eats the remnants of food etc. offered to
> Śaṅkara etc., would certainly be a cāṇḍāla. For thousands of crores of
> kalpas he is roasted in the fire in hell.** O best brāhmaṇas, the
> **remnants of offerings to gods like Rudra, are said to be equal to food offered to demons, yakṣas, goblins and like liquor and flesh.**
> Brāhmaṇas should not eat that food, the offering enjoyed by (these)
> gods.

Why is Shiva prasada compared to Liquor and Flesh? Is it really that impure?

Is this really true that eating Shiva's prasada leads to hell?

Comment: According to me, this is regarding Vaiṣṇavācāra, as per which Vaiṣṇavas only eat the food that's offered to Viṣṇu and not to other devatās. Also, it might mean that the offerings of matsya, madya or māṁsa that may be offered to Rudra, cannot be consumed by Vaiṣṇavas, but other offerings (which are vihita for Vaiṣṇavas) can be consumed.

Comment: @Bingming So this prohibition isn't applicable to those who have taken Saivadiksa, right?

Comment: of course, this shouldn't be applicable for Śaivas, Smārtas, or Śāktas, according to me. If Śaivas can't even eat the prasāda of their iṣṭa Śiva, that would be nonsensical..

Answer (score 0):

Shiva Purana 1.22.:

> The sages said:—
>
> 1. O good sage, we have heard before, that the offering of eatables (Naivedya) made to Śiva should not be taken by others. Please tell us decisively about this and also about the greatness of Bilva.
>
> Sūta said:—
>
> 2. O sages, all of you please hear now attentively. With pleasure I shall explain everything. All of you who take up Śiva’s sacred rites are really blessed.
> 3. A devotee of Śiva who is pure and clean, devoutly performing good rites and of fixed resolve shall partake of Śiva’s Naivedya. He shall abandon all thoughts which are not worthy of being entertained.
> 4. Even at the sight of the Naivedya of Śiva, all sins disappear. When it is taken in, crores of merits flock in, in no moment.
> 5. A thousand sacrifices are of no avail. Hundred millions of sacrifices are useless. When Śiva’s Naivedya is eaten one will attain identity with Siva.
> 6. If in a family Śiva’s Naivedya becomes popular with the members, that house becomes sacred and it can make others also sacred.
> 7. When Śiva’s Naivedya is offered it shall be accepted with pleasure and humility. It shall be eaten eagerly while remembering Siva.
> 8. If any one who is offered Śiva’s Naivedya delays taking it immediately, thinking that it can be taken afterwards, he will incur sins.
> 9. If anyone has no inclination to take Śiva’s Naivedya he becomes a sinner of sinners and is sure to fall into hell.
> 10. **After initiation in Saiva cult, the devotee shall partake of the offerings of eatables made to the phallic image whether conceived in the heart or made of moon-slab, silver, gold etc.**
> 11. **The Naivedya of all phallic icons is called a great favour and is auspicious. A devotee after initiation into Śaiva cult shall eat it.**
> 12. **Please listen to the decision with pleasure on partaking of Śiva’s Naivedya by persons who take initiation in other cults but maintain their devotion to Siva.**
>
> 13-15. With regard to the following phallic images viz:—that which is obtained from Śālagrāma stone, Rasalinga, lingas made of rock, silver, gold, crystals and gems, lingas installed by devas and siddhas, Kāśmīra lingas and Jyotirlingas, the partaking of the Naivedya of Śiva is on a par with the rite of Cāndrāyaṇa. Even the slayer of a brahmin if he partakes of the remains of the food offered to the God quells all his sins immediately.
>
> 16-17. **In regard to Bāṇalinga, metallic linga, Siddha-linga and Svayambhū-linga and in all other idols, Caṇḍa, one of the attendants of Śiva, is not authorised. Where Caṇḍa is not authorised, the food-offering can be partaken of by men with devotion. But no man shall partake of the food-offering where Caṇḍa is authorised.**
>
> 18. After performing the ceremonial ablution duly if any one drinks the water three times, all the three types of sins committed by him are quickly destroyed.
>
> 19-20. **If at all anything from Śivanaivedya is not to be taken it is that article which is actually put on the linga. O great sages, that what is not in contact with the linga is pure and as such, it can be partaken of. When it is in contact with Śālagrāma Śilā, it is pure and can be taken whether it is food-offering, leaf, flower, fruit or water.**
>
> 21a. O great sages, thus I have told you the decision about food-offering.

The reason for not taking Nirmalya of Chandeshwara are as follows.:

Kāmikā Tantra Chapter 3.:

> 524-525. He should worship Candesvara in the morth-east with sandal, flowers and other substances. **It is maintained that all the remains of the offerings made to Lord Siva should be dedicated to Candesvara. Some say that Candesvara is present on the top of the Linga;** others are of the view that he is present in the pedestal. Candesvara may be considered to be in the north-east side of the pedestal or to be present in the shrine specifically provided for him, outside the main shrine. **It is said that Candesvara is the manifested form of a part of Siva's anger.**
>
> 526-527. The eatables, sandal, flowers and such other materials, various objects kept there for the worship of Siva, garlands all these which are enjoyed by the Lord are called **'nirmalya (free from impurities).** The particles which are in the sthandila-linga and those which are the remins of the things enjoyed by Siva are **strictly for the enjoyment of Candesvara; they are unapproachable to the devotees and the common people. So, by all means, they should be kept apart, avoiding the intention to make use of them.**

Kāmikā Tantra Chapter 6.:

> 85-88. Then, having entered the main shrine, he should offer acamaniya-water to the Lord. **Having collected the remains of the materials (nirmalya) offered to Siva, he should offer them to Candesvara. Since it has attained a pure state free from all the traces of impurity, it is specifically called 'nirmalya'.** Having offered acamana-water to Candesvara, he should set the nirmalya in a pure place. The nirmalya may be offered to the water stored in the pit or may be offered to the fire or cow. **Since the human body is fettered with limiting bondages, the sadhaka or devotee should not consume the nirmalya.** Then, the worshipper should perform the fire-ritual, preceded by the sacramental activities related to the fire-pit.

The only way one can consume Bhagawan Shiva's (Purusha's) nirmalya is by making it into a bit malya prasada by making Lord Vishu (Prakriti) eat it first. Otherwise both Lord Chandeahwara and Lord Vishnu will curse. It's also because after Lord Chandeswara eating it, as a Bhakta, it first belongs to Lord Vishnu only.

Maha-Bhagwatam (Shakti Pithanka) Purana, Chapter 81.:

> 18-21. **He who offers to Lord Shiva is the best of men, after that he is also freed from all the sins and attains heaven. O Mune! All the offerings of ardha and other offerings to Lord Śambhu should also be offered in small amounts on the top of Shivalinga. O Mahabuddhe! In the context of eating Bhagawan Shankara's Nirmalya, it has been said that whatever Arghya etc. is offered on Shivalinga is inadmissible prasada and should not be eaten. All that is eatable only to Lord Vishnu and not to others. If someone else accepts it then he incurs the wrath of Vishnu. If the substance on top of the Shivalinga is touched to the Shaligram stone, it becomes acceptable (because then Lorx Vishnu eats it and it becomes Prasada of Lord Vishnu).** Again the Nirmalya of Anadilinga (Swayambhoolinga) is acceptable, by accepting it one attains Shivattva. After eating that Prasada, man himself becomes like Lord Shankara.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: Can Those who have taken Saivadiksa consume it directly? Without having to touch it with Salagrama or anything else

Comment: Yes, but other sampradaya have to touch it with Shaligram because. At the top of most Lingas, Bhagawan Chandeswar is present who is an ugra form of Mahadeva, so to calm him down Shaligrama is used. As only yoni (vishnu/shakti/prakriti) can calm the energy of linga (rudra/purusha). As Linga is infinite, jeevas who are finite can't consume it's power so to finite the energy Shaligrama is used as it's also finite.

Comment: How can those who have taken Sivadiksa consume it directly in that case? Who makes the energy finite for them?

Comment: The diksha mantra makes it finine for them. Because for example when a vaishnava prays to lord rudra he will pray him as sankarsana rudra the vyuha form which comes in sthiti chakra. So, for them the procedure will get lenthen as they will follow the procedure of pancharatra. And so on.